# Using XMLHttpRequest to fetch data from URL and display that data in a table?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to fetch data using XMLHttpRequest from a URL (GET API) in JSON form and then display that data in a HTML table.

I have been able to fetch the data, but not display it correctly.

My table displays as:

Name    ID  Generation  Type    Region

Name    ID  Generation  Type    Region

Instead of:

Name         ID   Generation    Type    Region

Bulabasaur   1    First         Grass   Kanto

My JSON data returns as:

```
[{
  ability: "Overgrow",
  category: "Seed"
  description: "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger.",
  gender: "M",
  generation: "First",
  height: "2' 04''",
  id: 1,
  name: "Bulbasaur",
  picture: "bulbasaur.jpg",
  region: "Kanto",
  type: "Grass, Poison",
  weakness: "Fire, Flying, Ice, Psychic",
  weight: "15.2"
}]
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/WorksheetPokemon/rest/pokemon";

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function pokemonTable(){

xhttp.open('GET', rootURL, true);

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

//console.log(this.responseText);
if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var status = xhttp.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        createTable(json);
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
  }
};

xhttp.send();

}


function createTable(json) {

console.log(json);

var tableBody = document.getElementById("table_body");  

// Populate table
json.forEach((row) => {

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    Object.keys(row).forEach((cell) => {

        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.textContent = cell;
        tr.appendChild(td);

    });

    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
});

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pokemonTable());
```

Comment: What does *but not display it correctly* mean? Can you show us what the table should look like and how the data in your JSON is structured?

Comment: So my table should be: Name         ID Generation Type Region
                                     Bulbasaur 1 First                 Grass Kanto
But its coming back with: Name ID Generation Type Region
                                         Name ID Generation Type Region

Comment: my JSON data comes back as:                                                                                 ability: "Overgrow"
category: "Seed"
description: "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger."
gender: "M"
generation: "First"
height: "2' 04''"
id: 1
name: "Bulbasaur"
picture: "bulbasaur.jpg"
region: "Kanto"
type: "Grass, Poison"
weakness: "Fire, Flying, Ice, Psychic"
weight: "15.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys()` will return all the keys from the object in an array.
What you need is the values, which you can get with `Object.values()`.

```
function createTable(json) {

  var tableBody = document.getElementById("table_body");  

  // Populate table
  json.forEach((row) => {

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    Object.values(row).forEach((cell) => {

        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.textContent = cell;
        tr.appendChild(td);

    });

    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, the first param of ForEach callback is row. When you use Object.keys(row), you're reading the keys of those fields. That's why you table is displaying the name of those fields and not its content.

Instead of use Object.key(row), you must use this:

```
json.forEach((row) => {

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    Object.keys(row).forEach((cell) => {

        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.textContent = row[cell];
        tr.appendChild(td);

    });

    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
});
```